# How do I search my Outlook calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

There's an appointment in my calendar for a date in the future that I can't find. I know it's in there somewhere, but I can't work out how to search appointment items. What am I missing?

Apparently, I'm missing the advanced search dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 2007 there is an updated search mechanism at the top of the appointment book. You should be able to search by name in there.

If that doesn't work, you can change the view. The best way is to add the "Advanced" toolbar (View menu --> toolbars --> Advanced). At the end of that toolbar is a drop down for views. The default view is "Day Week Month", but you can change it to "Active Appointments" or "Category". The advantage is that they are listed by name and can be sorted by the column headers to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

From the calendar view in Outlook 2010, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> opens up Advanced Find, where you can search appointments by subject/body/etc.

This also works in Outlook 2007, and is a way to search for text in a calendar item (appointment, event…) regardless of date (past or future). For some reason, at least in Outlook 2007, the "Search Calendar" box in the Calendar header does not work at all in normal calendar view.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Outlook 2016 but I remember using similar searches in previous outlook versions.

```
start:>=04/06/2018
```

will find all events starting after April 6th 2018

```
start:04/06/2018..06/01/2018
```

will find all events starting April 6th and June 1st 2018.

You can replace `start:` with `end:` to find events based on their end date. 
You can use `>=`, `<=`, `<`, `>`, `=`, and `..` as a range operator.

Answer (score 0):

In my Outlook 2021 there is a search field in the application title:
[image]